# Can I declare a number as a variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Am I allowed to do this in JavaScript?

```
var 1 = "me";
var 2 = "you";
var 3 = "we";
```

If not, what's the work around it?

My goal is to create a game where a random number is generated then I answer what that number represents.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about extremely basic aspects of JavaScript, namely what is a valid identifier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: @RUJordan - isn't the question really -- how can I define values for numbers (with an answer of dictionary or array) not what valid characters are for variable names?

Comment: It's an implicit question. He asked if those were allowed variable names. Not to mention it shows no attempt, and it's very basic stuff. So it should be closed.

Comment: Although this is a naive question, how do you expect a beginner to ask about arrays if they don't even know arrays exist?

Comment: Maybe not ask about arrays, but at least do a simple search before asking. RUJordan gave a pretty good link and I don't think he got it from his recurrent bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want an array:

```
var answers = ["","me","you","we"];
```

then:

```
answers[1]
```

has this value:

```
"me"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an object:

```
var obj = {1: "me",
           2: "you",
           3: "we"};
```

Then when you generate the random number you can look up the associated value using `obj[number]`.  Of course if the numbers are always in sequence you could use an array instead, you would just need a dummy value at the beginning since array indexing starts at `0`, so doing something like `var arr = [null, "me", "you", "we"];` would work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  The workaround is to start the variable name with a letter:

```
var a1 = "me";
var a2 = "you";
var a3 = "we";
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use array

```
var answers = ["","me","you","us"];



  answers[1] returns me
      answers[2] returns you
       answers[3] returns us
```

or use a letter as prefix

like

```
var b1 = "me";
var b2 = "you";
var b3 = "we";
```